# Inheriting static dict via dict.update()

Tags: python, inheritance, dictionary

Subclasses in my application model inherit static attributes (stored as dictionaries) from the superclass, with each subclass using update() to add fields to it's own static field. But this didn't work how I expected it to. Here's the simple version:

```
In [19]: class A(object):
    s = {1:1} 

In [20]: class B(A):
    s = A.s.update({2:2})

In [21]: class C(B):
    s = B.s.update({3:3})

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-4eea794593c8> in <module>()
----> 1 class C(B):
      2     s = B.s.update({3:3})
      3 

<ipython-input-21-4eea794593c8> in C()
      1 class C(B):
----> 2     s = B.s.update({3:3})
      3 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update
```

This DID work, however, when I was concatenating fields to a static list in each subclass. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` doesn't return a `dict`; it just modifies the receiver in place. For example, after `s = A.s.update({2:2})`, `A.s` is modified, and `s` is `None`. You can instead write something like

```
s = dict(B.s, **{3: 3})
```

to achieve what you want. Note that in python 3, this won't work since keyword arguments are enforced to be strings. You can write a helper function:

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    d = dict(d1)
    d.update(d2)
    return d
```

And use `s = merge(B.s, {3: 3})` instead.

Comment: Keyword argument names must be strings. This is enforced, so `dict(B.s, **{3: 3})` doesn't work. Copy it and update the copy instead.

Comment: Perfect! That explains why dict.copy().update({3:3}) didn't work either.

Comment: @user2357112 I just tried this in python2.7, and it seems to work fine. It gives an error in python3 though.